# Jquery MagicLine using background image?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I've got a basic navigation with only top level items. There is an oversized background image (navigation is 100px tall, bg image is 200px tall) that is added to the current page being visited.

```
 <ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I'd love to be able to emulate the behavior of [jQuery MagicLine](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/) but use my background image and have it move from item to item as the user mouses over other navigation links.

Is this doable in jQuery? CSS3?

Comment: So, you want the background image to slide back and forth behind the links as the mouse hovers over them? Are the links the same width, and the bg image as well?

Comment: Exactly. I can make them the same width. The bg image will always be the same.

Comment: Ok, do you need complete cross browser support? It would be interesting to try to do this with CSS transitions, but only modern browsers would support it. Otherwise we could put something together with jQuery.

Comment: CSS would be cool, its a limited audience site. As long as it degrades to just having the `.current-menu-item` state it'll do the job.

Comment: I was thinking about this, and I can't think of a pure CSS solution. If you mouseout from your first link and then mouseover your last, I don't see a good way to slide the image under links 2-4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted the solution here: http://www.nextdesigns.ca/magicline/index.html

It's embarrassingly simple, actually. In the end, I needed only to fiddle with the CSS a bit.

I updated a couple items in the CSS. I added a static width here, as discussed:

```
#example-one li { 
    display: inline-block;  
    width:100px; //NEW
}
```

Then, for the MagicLine, I updated the dimensions and background properties:

```
#magic-line { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100px; //NEW
    height: 50px; //NEW
    background: #fff url(bg.png); //NEW
    z-index:-1;
}
```

I popped bg.png next to the CSS. It is a simple image with a grayish background. You could swap it out for any 100px by 50px image. Please mark as the answer if it helped.